# windows Installer that is restricted to X times

Tags: windows, installation

I need a windows installer that can install my program only X number of times.  Say 10 or 20 or a defined number I set.  Then the installer ceases to operate or can give a message to contact my company.
Ed

Comment: I have a feeling that this question would be better suited for SO, however don't open a new question there, this one will be migrated if necessary.

Comment: Unless your software is Enterprise class, please reconsider. There's some software I have had to support, works well, reasonably priced, that I will never recommend or approve again - because the hassles of their installation procedure are not worth it. And the support they have needed to give us probably wasn't worth it for them either.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions.

- One solution that is quite common is to require online authentication for the program for each new install.

Solutions that may be viable in some situation:

- Self modifying executable. Just let the installer modify itself and reduce some counter. But it is easily defeatable  by making multiple copies of the executable.
- If you want to limit the installer only on one computer add some registry key and check that. Also easily defeatable

Comment: Just imagine the consequences of an online authentication server that breaks or goes down.  Not only do you have a server that is down, but you also have dozens or hundreds of clients calling in thinking that you've stolen their money or screwed them over.  What a bad idea!

Comment: Plus for the online authentication, minus for the other suggestions. Online authentication against keys embedded in setup.exe's is the only way this is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

1. In my opinion the best way to doing this is using a [hardware block/dongle](http://www.safenet-inc.com/Products/Software_Rights_Management/Sentinel_Protection_and_Licensing/Sentinel_HASP/Sentinel_HASP_Hardware_Keys.aspx). They're awful for the user, but they work in limiting access. The other advantage to these blocks, is that you can install the software on numerous pcs, but the software can only run on the pcs with plugged in usb keys.
2. Another solution to have some form of an encrypted file/db, that whenever an installation is flagged as complete, it adds a value. When the number of values reaches X, then setup won't work anymore

**EDIT**
the real issue is that most applications are installed using a dvd/cd, in order to limit the number of installations, you need to be able to write back to the dvd. I don't think this is feasible in most cases.